# datepicker is not working for dynamicaly created table rows

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2, datepicker, struts2-jquery

I tried to implement to provide users to create rows dynamically. Rows are created successfully but `datepicker` filed is not working. My codes are like the following:

```
    <tr id="input_row_0" class="input_row"> 
        <td> <sj:datepicker theme="simple" name="productionDate" displayFormat="ymmdd" maxlength="6" size="8" showButtonPanel="false"/> </td> 
        <td> <s:textfield name="productName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="add_new"> 
        <td colspan="4" align="right"> Add New Rows </td>
    </tr>
```

And javascript/jquery codes for adding dynamic rows:

```
$(function(){
    // Add New Row    
    var counter = 1;  
   $( "#add_new" ).click(function() {
        var html = '<tr id="input_row_'+counter+'" class="input_row" >'+$("#input_row_0").html()+"</tr>"; 
        $('.input_row:last').after(html) ; 
        $('.input_row:last button').attr('alt', 'input_row_'+counter) ; 

          counter++; 
    }); 
    });
```

Can anybody suggest me which part of the code I have to change so that the `datepicker` can work?

[Note: I am working on JSP page and Struts 2 is used here]

Comment: "Datepicker is not working" means nothing.  Not popping up? Not producing dates properly formatted for SQL queries?...

Comment: It's not popping up the dated. But working fine by manual typing to the datepicker field.

Comment: Probably you need to set the showOn and/or showOptions attributes. http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/DatePickerTag

Comment: I just tried with that also. But still the same problem.

Comment: JSP tags are rendered on the server-side. You cannot render it on the client.

Comment: But is there any way to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `.datePicker()` explicitly on the newly created objects.

For e.g.

```
$('.input_row:last button').datepicker({
      showButtonPanel: true,
      showOn: "both",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
      buttonText: "Calendar",
      altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
```

[Reference](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#buttonbar)

[Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)